# Jupyter Notebook Multiprocessing code not working

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing

I am new in python i have Anaconda Pyton 3.9
I was studying about Multiprocessing.

When i try this code

```
from multiprocessing import Process # gerekli kütüphaneyi çağıracağız.

import time

def subfunc1():
    time.sleep(2)
    print("subfunc1: Baslatildi")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("subfunc1: Sonlandi")
    time.sleep(2)

def subfunc2():
    time.sleep(2)
    print("subfunc2: Baslatildi")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("subfunc2: Sonlandi")
    time.sleep(2)
    
def mainfunc():
    print("mainfunc: Baslatildi")
    pr1 = Process(target=subfunc1)
    pr2 = Process(target=subfunc2)
    pr1.start()
    pr2.start()
    print("mainfunc: Sonlandi")
    
if __name__ == '__main__': # Main kod bloğunun içerisindeyken main fonk çağır!
    mainfunc()

result is

    mainfunc: Baslatildi
    mainfunc: Sonlandi
```

When i use Visual Code with Python 3.9 i have a virtual and code works!
Visual Code uses Anaconda's python 3.9 within a virtual env!

Could you please help me? Whey this code can't work properly in Jupyter Notebook?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Am I correct in assuming you are running this on ms-windows or macOS?

In that case, `multiprocessing` will not work in an interactive interpreter like IPython. This is covered in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers), see the "note":

> Functionality within this package requires that the `__main__` module be importable by the children. This is covered in Programming guidelines however it is worth pointing out here. This means that some examples, such as the `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` examples will not work in the interactive interpreter.

This is caused by the `spawn` [start method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods) used on these operating systems.

One possible fix is to save you code in a script, and to make sure that creating `multiprocessing` objects is done within the `__main__`-block. Another is in the comment by Aaron below

Comment: As an addition to this answer, Jupyter can use multiprocessing as long as the target function is imported from an outside .py file which is importable. It cannot be defined within the notebook file. There are many 3rd party libraries that attempt to make multiprocessing in jupyter work better, such as `multiprocess` (missing the -ing) which uses `dill` rather than `pickle` to send the target function as well as the process object to the new instance.

Comment: In my case `multiprocessing` is used inside a module installed in "editable" mode with `pip install -e` and it works just fine in Jupyter interactive window for `with Pool(4) as p: ...`