# Python. Multiprocessing/Multithreading in Windows for not web-scraping task

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have NLP project in Windows environment and cannot find Multiprocessing or Multithreading module to make my code faster. Function it self is very long to publish here, but meaning is to transform incoming strings and get some metrics. It looks like this:

```
from nltk.metrics.distance jaccard_distance, jaro_winkler_similarity
incoming_list = ('string1', 'string2', 'string3')

def recognizer(string, lib = lib):
   output = []
   distances = [(jaro_winkler_similarity(string, word), word) for word in lib if 
   i[:round(len(i)*0.7)] == word[:round(len(i)*0.7)]]
   prediction = max(distances)
   if prediction >= 0.9:
      output.append(prediction)
   else:
      if re.match(pattern, string):
         distances = [(jaccard_distance(set(string), set(word.split(' '))), word) for 
         word in list(data.values())]
         prediction = min(distances)
         if prediction < 0.2: 
         #and so on
   return output
```

Multiprocessing.Pool and from concurrent.ProcessPoolExecutor do not work in Windows. This code working in Linux and Mac, but simply pending in Windows

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager
from itertools import repeat
manager = Manager()
output = manager.dict()
with Pool(3) as p:
  p.starmap(reader, zip(output, repeat(Incoming_list, repeat(lib), repeat(other_args))))
  p.close()
  p.join()
print(output)
```

I`v tried with Multithreading but execution time is 100% the same.
Here is example:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from itertools import repeat

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as executor:
    results = list(executor.map(recognizer, Incoming_list, repeat(lib), repeat(other_args))
```

I need some Windows fork for Multiprocessing or any advice regarding Multithreading

Comment: _Multiprocessing.Pool and from concurrent.ProcessPoolExecutor do not work in Window_ - what makes you think so? What does _do not work_ mean exactly?

Comment: And I would suggest to check [What are the differences between the threading and multiprocessing modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18114285/4046632) in order to understand what will be beneficial in your case. From the scarce information provided about the nature of the task, it looks like it's a calculation intensive task and probably you may benefit from a multiprocessing

Comment: Yes, I understand difference threading and multiprocessing. Initially I have made this tool in Linux environment because first two projects was with Linux server. And I`v used multiprocessing.PooMultiprocessing.Pool and from concurrent.ProcessPoolExecutor simply pending there...   I have added my code with Pool.
Threading was just research of any alternative.

Answer (score 0):

> Multiprocessing.Pool ... do not work in Windows

I disagree.

You are describing a mature library that has been
well tested on Windows for more than a decade.
You did not show us application code which
relies on the `multiprocessing` module.

We live with the GIL.
Given that your task is compute-bound,
to take advantage of 8 cores you will
need 8 GILs, 8 interpreters running
in 8 child processes.

---

> I've tried with Multithreading, but execution time is 100% the same.

Yes, this is not surprising.
The code you showed is compute bound.
We could spawn N threads, but each will
need to acquire the GIL, so only a single
thread will run concurrently.
Threading is useful for I/O heavy workloads,
such as a web server which spends much of
its time waiting for TCP to move payloads around the net.

The performance and behavior you report
is expected; it is not a bug.

Comment: Hi. I`v updated post and added code with Pool, working on Linux and Max, but pending in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems like problem can be solved be adding "if **name** == '**main**':"
and running from command line.
In my case:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   with Pool(5) as executor:
        prediction = executor.starmap(recognizer, zip(Incoming_list, repeat(libs), 
        repeat(other args))
```

In Jupiter it still pending

Comment: Now, using Jupiter is something you never mentioned in original post. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/47313732/4046632 and e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73437250/4046632

Comment: You also have to include `manager = Manager()` within the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block as it creates a process. For Jupyter, the worker function `recognizer` has to be in a separate module that gets imported to be found.